# Nested IF not working properly in worksheet; How to fix?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to do nested `IF` between two variables in a worksheet, but I'm not getting the desired results. Is it because the cells I'm trying to compare are in the formula?

The result I want is:

When Column A *and* Column D results are `TRUE`, I'll get a result of "Same Year + Leap Year"; if not, it must show "Others".

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

When using the AND function where your cells contain TRUE or FALSE, it's enough to pass the cell reference to the function. So you should use this:

```
=IF(AND(A3,D3),"Same Y + Leap Year","Others")
```